# External 27" monitor click, refreshing, turning off with MacBook pro 16"

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, hdmi, macbook

I have a Retina Macbook pro 2019 (MacBookPro16,1) model, I'm on MacOS Catalina.

I have two 27" external monitors

- Acer S271HL
- Benq GW2780

I'm using a hdmi cable to usb c, with some angle adapters for each.

I'm experiencing several kinds of issues with the Benq monitor.

- sometimes it makes click noises.
- sometimes it kind of refreshes, like it's quickly been turned on and off.
- also it goes off completely, until I change the refresh rate to eith 50 / 60 hertz.

Obviously it sounds like an issue with the Benq monitor, unfortunetly I've lost the receipt, although it is around a year old.

However I guess it could also be related to my Mac ?
For full disclosure, I do experience my mac fan going a lot, but I put this down the applications I'm running, but I guess this may be important.

I just wondered if anyone had any suggestions of what I might do to fix the problem.

I've been expecting the monitor to fail for months, but it hasn't.

EDIT:
I'm not using any adapters just cables.

Comment: I'd guess the additional fan noise is a direct result of running 2 external displays & not a symptom of what could either be a cable fail or display fail [not sure how to tell without some process of elimination]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suddenly occured to me to try switching cables.

Initially I had two cables the same. But then I needed one of them longer and I bought a new cable.

The new cable is faulty!